# Post a form in the remote url

Tags: post, http-post

I have an URL. There is a form in that URL and I know it's name and the form action.

E.g:

url:

```
www.abc.com/123.html
```

form:

```
<form action="POST.php" method="post" name="form">
    <input id="id" name="name" type="text">
</form>
```

My question is how do I post this form and get the response? I have tried several answers but they didn't work well. Any programming language is fine.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in PHP.

see this [Submitting form to remote server.](http://www.maheshchari.com/submit-a-form-to-remote-server-with-php-curl/)

Comment: the url in the example is a php file, which is not the same as my case